# Freeing Memory passed into a function

Tags: c, memory-management

Im currently building a set of structures that will store the state of an uno game. The game is stored in a struct that holds the following data. I am representing the deck of cards by a struct called Deck that will operate as a stack defined like so:

```
typedef struct _card *Card;
typedef struct _deck *Deck;
typedef struct _listCard *ListCard;
typedef struct _player *Player;

struct _card {
    value value;
    color color;
    suit suit;
};

struct _listCard {
    Card card;
    ListCard next;
};

struct _player {
    // Integer between 0 and 3.
    int player_id;
    //  Player has a hand (a deck of cards)
    Deck hand;
};

// A deck is an ADT for a linked lis of ListCards.
struct _deck {
    // Keep track of the deck.
    int num_cards;

    // Stack of cards in the deck.
    // Keep track of the top of the deck
    ListCard top;
};

struct _gamestate {
    int curr_player;
    int turn_number;
    Card curr_card;
};

struct _game {
    Deck draw_pile;
    Deck discard_pile;
    Player players;
    GameState game_state;
    int turnNumber;
    int deckSize;
};
```

I have implemented a bunch of functions and am now trying to write a function that will delete the deck.

```
static void freeDeck(Deck deck) {
    ListCard curr = deck->top;
    if (curr == NULL) {
        free(deck);
        return;
    }
    while (curr != NULL) {
        ListCard temp = curr;
        destroyCard(temp->card);
        curr = curr->next;
        free(temp);
    }
    free(deck);
}

void destroyCard(Card card) {
    free(card);
}
```

Now the issue I have is with implementing a pop function, and using the returned value of that function to move a card from one deck to another (like taking the top card of the deck and placing it in a discard pile).

```
static Card popCard(Deck deck) {
    // sanity check
    if (deck == NULL) {
        return NULL;

    // Can't pop from an empty stack.
    } else if (deck->top == NULL) {
        return NULL;

    // Only one card in the deck.
    } else if (deck->top->next == NULL) {
        Card temp = deck->top->card;
        free(deck->top);
        deck->top = NULL;

        return temp;
    }
    // Otherwise: at least two cards in the deck:

    Card val = deck->top->card;
    ListCard temp = deck->top->next;
    free(deck->top);
    deck->top = temp;
    return val;
}
```

This is my function to pop and this is my function to add:

```
static void addToDeck(Deck deck, Card card) {
    if (deck->top == NULL) {
        deck->top = newListCard(card);
    } else {
        addCard(deck, card);
    }
    deck->num_cards++;
}

static ListCard newListCard(Card card) {
    ListCard newCard = malloc(sizeof(struct _listCard));
    newCard->next = NULL;
    newCard->card = card;
    return newCard;
}

static void addCard(Deck deck, Card card) {
    assert(deck != NULL);
    ListCard newCard = newListCard(card);
    newCard->next = deck->top;
    deck->top = newCard;
}
```

I am calling the function to perform the operation above like so:

```
addToDeck(newgame->discard_pile, popCard(newgame->draw_pile));
```

However this brings up an invalid pointer error in gdb when I try to free the deck with

```
freeDeck(newgame->discard_pile)
```

I am new to C memory management and I believe the issue is with trying to free memory that does not point anymore to the start of the point where it was malloc'd.

EDIT:

The game itself is initialised like so:

```
Game newGame(int deckSize, value values[], color colors[], suit suits[]) {
    // malloc a new game.
    Game newgame = malloc(sizeof(game));

    if (newgame == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory");
        return NULL;
    }
    // Otherwise there will be no cards to put into the draw pile.
    if (deckSize <= NUM_PLAYERS*DEFAULT_HAND) {
        return NULL;
    }

    newgame->deckSize = deckSize;

    // malloc the players in the game.

    Player players = malloc(NUM_PLAYERS*sizeof(struct _player));
    if (players == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Instatiate each player object
    int i = 0;
    while (i < NUM_PLAYERS) {
        players[i].player_id = i;
        players[i].hand = newDeck();
        i++;
    }
    // Assign the players to the game.
    newgame->players = players;

    // Create decks of discard pile and draw_pile
    newgame->draw_pile = newDeck();
    newgame->discard_pile = newDeck();
    // loop through each of the values, colours and suits and create the necessary objects to star the game.

    i = 0;
    while (i < deckSize) {

        // Create a card from the array of values, colours and suits.
        Card card = newCard(values[i], colors[i], suits[i]);

        // Give each player 7 cards.
        if (i < DEFAULT_HAND*NUM_PLAYERS) {
            addToDeck(newgame->players[i % 4].hand, card);
        // After we have given each player seven cards fill the draw pile.
        } else {
            addToDeck(newgame->draw_pile, card);
        }

        i++;
    }

    // Push the first card onto the stack of the discard_pile.
    addToDeck(newgame->discard_pile, popCard(newgame->draw_pile));

    //Create the initial game state.

    GameState init = malloc(sizeof(struct _gamestate));
    init->curr_card = newgame->discard_pile->top->card;
    init->curr_player = 0;
    init->turn_number = 1;
    newgame->game_state = init;

    printGame(newgame);
    return newgame;
}

static Deck newDeck(void) {
    Deck deck = malloc(sizeof(struct _deck));

    if (deck == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory");
            return NULL;
    }

    deck->num_cards = 0;
    deck->top = NULL;
    return deck;
}
```

The game is freed with this function:

```
void destroyGame(Game game) {
    GameState state = game->game_state;
    destroyCard(state->curr_card);
    free(state);
    Player players = game->players;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < NUM_PLAYERS) {
        freeDeck(players[i].hand);
        i++;
    }
    free(game->players);
    freeDeck(game->draw_pile);
    freeDeck(game->discard_pile);
    free(game);
}
```

The free function is operating as expected up until I call freeDeck(game->discard_pile), by which i get an invalid pointer on the element that I popped off the draw_pile deck. Some more testing has shown that this occurs every time I pop a card off the deck.

The main function at the moment just calls the following:

```
int main(void) {
    int decksize = 50;
    value values[decksize];
    color colors[decksize];
    suit suits[decksize];

    for (int i = 0; i < decksize; i++) {
            values[i] = rand() % 16;
            colors[i] = rand() % 16;
            suits[i] = rand() % 16;
    }
    Game cardgame = newGame(50, values, colors, suits);
    destroyGame(cardgame);
}
```

Where exactly is my error and how can i fix it?

Comment: Please provide the full program.  I do not see main()

Comment: What exactly did GDB say about that error?  Specifically, what was the pointer that was causing the problem?  What were `newgame->discard_pile`, `newgame->discard_pile->top`, `newgame->discard_pile->top->card`, `newgame->discard_pile->top->next`, etc?  How did you initialize `newgame->discard_pile`?  Figuring out those cues will be helpful for diagnosing your problem.

Comment: Have you tried to narrow the problem by simply creating a deck and then deleting it immediately?  Don't attempt to pop a card from one deck to another between creating the deck and deleting it. You might want to use eclipse to and use the debugger to walk through your code step by step

Comment: I don't think there is anything wrong with the code you posted, besides not decrementing `num_cards` in `popCard`, but that shouldn't cause such an error. Maybe you have already freed `newgame->discard_pile` or something in it before calling `freeDeck` on it?

Comment: The function freeDeck works fine when I have not popped any element off the stack.

For instance just building a a stack of say 10 cards and calling freeDeck works fine. 

The error exclusively occurs when I try to free an element that I have popped off a deck and placed onto another deck.